# AttributeError with user.is_staff

Tags: python, django, authentication

Noob working on [official tutorial part5 testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial05/):
"Perhaps logged-in admin users should be allowed to see unpublished Questions, but not ordinary visitors."

So here my relevant code (with some un-working variation after the #'s):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
    user = User

    #def get_queryset(self):
    def get_queryset(request):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        #user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
        #user = User
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        else:
            return Question.objects.exclude(choice__isnull=True).filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
                                   ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Is it possible to do something like that?
It give the error:

```
type object 'User' has no attribute 'is_staff'
```

Thank you

Comment: This error sounds like it's saying your `user` variable is actually the class `User` not a class instance of `User`. Are you sure it's the exact place that caused the error? Please post your full stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.user` in this case is your *`User` model class, not the model instance*. The problem is coming from how you define the `get_queryset()` instance method:

```
def get_queryset(request):
```

Basically, `request` is not a current request object - it is taken the `self`'s place and is pointing to the `ListView` instance. Then you are getting the `request.user` which is a `User` model class.

Get the current user from the `self.request.user`:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        else:
            return Question.objects.exclude(choice__isnull=True).filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
                                   ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```